# Minimizing cost with restricted amounts on nodes (graph theory related)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a complete bipartite graph with costs on the <strike>vertices</strike> (edit: edges). Suppose there is some number of goods stored in every node of the first set and I want to transfer all of them to the nodes of the second set through the <strike>vertices</strike> (edit: edges) while minimizing the cost.

However, each node of the second set has a capacity, meaning that they can't store a number of goods greater than that capacity. It is given that the total capacity of the nodes of the second set is greater or equal to the total number of goods in the nodes of the first set.

I'm looking for a way to transfer the goods to minimize the cost while taking into account the capacities of the nodes.

I feel that it is somehow related to minimum cost maximum flow problems but can't seem to find a way to solve it. Is there a general solution to this kind of problems?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Vertex" and "node" typically mean the same thing. They are connected by "edges".

Comment: The problem isn't well-defined. How are costs on vertices applied to get the cost of moving goods?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking, but problems sounding a lot like this can be solved using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. Very often it doesn't seem to fit the original problem exactly because the number of agents isn't equal to the number of tasks, but you can make the problem fit by creating dummy agents or dummy tasks with costs or benefits set equal to zero, or by turning one agent with capacity K into K agents with capacity one.

Comment: Why is this formulated as a graph theory problem? You can move from any vertex on the left to any vertrx on the right. You could have stored the entire load of goods in a single left side vertex. Which meas that vertices on the left side are not interesting at all. You have a set of storages with given cost and capacity you need to fill. The solution is trivial, you fill the cheapest one to the top, repeat until all goods are placed in storage.

Comment: If you cannot split the content of left-side nodes, it means you have a bunch of knapsacks you have to fill. Same as before but to fill each individual right side node you need to solve an instance of the knapsack problem.

Comment: My bad. Changed the description. Vertices should be edges instead...